# Stocktwits API - how to login automatically

Tags: php, stocktwits

I'm trying to develop something that work with Stocktwits. We have an account that we want to use, so every time we have a new post on our site, it would be posted to Stocktwits.

https://api.stocktwits.com/developers/docs/authentication
However, following their api documentation, it seems that I would always have to authentication on the browser and click on "YES" to allow access to get the access code.

```
 https://api.stocktwits.com/api/2/oauth/authorize?client_id=<client_id>&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://www.example.com&scope=read,watch_lists,publish_messages,publish_watch_lists,direct_messages,follow_users,follow_stocks
```

What we need is a way to bypass this step so we always authorize our own account to use our own app and then just start using the API functionalities in php rather than visiting a browser and click "YES" to get the access code.

Is that possible to do that?

Comment: From their documentation, it appears that there are methods for app authentication using CURL : [link]https://api.stocktwits.com/developers/docs/api

Comment: do you know how can I translate the following to php? cURL [ about cURL ] curl -X GET -u <username> -p https://api.stocktwits.com/api/2/oauth/authorize -d 'client_id=<client id>&response_type=token&redirect_uri=http://www.example.com&scope=read,watch_lists,publish_messages,publish_watch_lists,follow_users,follow_stocks'

Comment: There are API wrappers that you may want to explore. A quick search yielded this : [link]https://github.com/jayzalowitz/StocktwitsAPI  but there are probably more.

Comment: I already checked those wrapper classes. Unfortunately, none of them shows how to login using username and password on the server, they all go through a browser asking for permission.

Comment: A solution here [link]https://zackburt.com/financialmarkets/index.php/2016/07/19/automated-posting-to-the-stocktwits-api-using-queues/  uses Amazon's Queue Service (SQS)

Comment: [link]https://www.phpclasses.org/blog/package/7700/post/5-4-Ways-to-Access-an-OAuth-API-Without-User-Interaction.html